# create a daily planner program in python dictionary

Tags: python

I am a beginner just started using python. I am trying to write a program that stores a to-do list for each weekdays and weekends. I want a key in the dictionary for each day of the week and each key has a value of a list that stores the to-do list items. 
the program needs to pop up the prompt questions to have something like:

Prompt: What would you like to do?

> add

Prompt: What day?

> Monday

Prompt: What would you like to add to Monday's to-do list?

> practice

And the to-do list needs to be able to hold multiple items per day (new one won't replace the old one).

I am not sure my code is making sense or not, could you please help me look at it?

```py
myDict = {} 
days = {"monday":None , "tuesday":None , "wednesday":None , "thursday":None , "friday":None }
monday = {}

q1= input("Prompt: What would you like to do? ")
if q1 == "add":
    q2 = input("Prompt: What day?")
if q2 in days:
    q3 = input("Prompt: What would you like to add to " + q2 + "'s to-do list?")
else:
    print("Invalid entry - please enter a correct day of the week (like Monday or monday).")

days["monday"] = q3
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_todo_list = {"monday": [],
                "tuesday": [],
                "wednesday": [],
                "thursday": [],
                "friday": [],
                "saturday": [],
                "sunday": []}

while True:
    q1 = input("Prompt: What would you like to do? ")
    if q1 == "add":
        q2 = input("Prompt: What day? ").lower()
        if q2 in my_todo_list:
            q3 = input("Prompt: What would you like to add to " + q2 + "'s to-do list? ")
            my_todo_list[q2].append(q3)
        else:
            print("Invalid entry - please enter a correct day of the week (like Monday or monday).")
    else:
        print("User entered - " + q1 + ". Exiting program.")
        break

print(my_todo_list)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by assigning each day in the dictionary an empty list to start off. This way you can store multiple items like the following:

```
days = {"monday": [] , "tuesday": [] , "wednesday": [] , "thursday": [] , "friday": []}

# adding item1 and item2 in the to-do list of monday
# this uses the append method to add new items into the list
days['monday'].append('item1')
days['monday'].append('item2')

print(days['monday'])
```

As a side note, it seems like you want to add multiple items before your program ends. In that case you need to create a while loop with an exit condition. Ex. q1, q2 or q3 == 'quit()'.